# express define routes confusion app.use()

Tags: express, routes

app.use('/api/users',require('./routes/api/users'));

app.use('/api/auth',require('./routes/api/auth'));

app.use('/api/profile',require('./routes/api/profile'));

app.use('/api/posts',require('./routes/api/posts'))

When i change the routes from 'api' to any other words the server keep giving me 404 not found error and I also changed axio method to the corresponding words.

for example app.use('/ddd/posts',require('./routes/api/posts')) and corresponding axios: const res = await axios.get('/ddd/posts');

please help

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be more clear about what you are changing. Show a single route example, indicate if it is working correctly in that state, then show what you've changed, and include the exact error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

If this:

```
app.use('/api/posts',require('./routes/api/posts'))
```

works with:

```
axios.get('/api/posts');
```

Then, this:

```
app.use('/ddd/posts',require('./routes/api/posts'))
```

will work just fine with:

```
axios.get('/ddd/posts');
```

Unless there is something interfering with your modified server.  Things that could be interfering:

1. A proxy configured only to allow certain paths through
2. Your new server didn't get started properly, perhaps because the prior generation of the server is still running

Comment: yes i was using the proxy setting /api/** so if not start with api the error occurred